# TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to login to imdb and **scrape** some data.

Here is my code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import FormRequest


class lisTopSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name= 'imdbLog'
    allowed_domains = ['imdb.com']
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.imdb.com/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https://www.imdb.com/registration/ap-signin-handler/imdb_us&openid.identity=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=imdb_us&openid.mode=checkid_setup&siteState=eyJvcGVuaWQuYXNzb2NfaGFuZGxlIjoiaW1kYl91cyIsInJlZGlyZWN0VG8iOiJodHRwczovL3d3dy5pbWRiLmNvbS8_cmVmXz1sb2dpbiJ9&openid.claimed_id=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0&tag=imdbtag_reg-20'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        token = response.xpath('//form/input[@name="appActionToken"]/@value').get()
        appAction = response.xpath('//form/input[@name="appAction"]/@value').get()
        siteState = response.xpath('//form/input[@name="siteState"]/@value').get()
        openid = response.xpath('//form/input[@name="openid.return_to"]/@value').get() 
        prevRID = response.xpath('//form/input[@name="prevRID"]/@value').get()
        workflowState = response.xpath('//form/input[@name="workflowState"]/@value').get() 
        create = response.xpath('//input[@name="create"]/@value').get() 
        metadata1 = response.xpath('//input[@name="metadata1"]/@value').get()

        base_url = 'https://www.imdb.com/lists/tt0120852'
        if 'login' in response.url:
            return scrapy.Request(base_url, callback = self.listParse)
        else:
            return scrapy.Request(response,cookies=[{
                'appActionToken':token,
                'appAction':appAction,
                'siteState':siteState,
                'openid.return_to':openid,
                'prevRID':prevRID,
                'workflowState':workflowState,
                'email':'....@gmail.com',
                'create':create,
                'passwrod':'....',
                'metadata1':metadata1,
                }], callback=self.parse)
        
    def listParse(self, response):
        listsLinks = response.xpath('//div[2]/strong')
        for link in listsLinks:
            list_url = response.urljoin(link.xpath('.//a/@href').get())
            yield scrapy.Request(list_url, callback=self.parse_list, meta={'list_url': list_url})
        
        next_page_url = response.xpath('//a[@class="flat-button next-page "]/@href').get()
        if next_page_url is not None:
            next_page_url = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.listParse)            

    #Link of each list
    def parse_list(self, response):
        list_url = response.meta['list_url']
        myRatings = response.xpath('//div[@class="ipl-rating-star small"]/span[2]/text()').getall()

        yield{
            'list': list_url,
            'ratings': myRatings,
        }
```

First I was getting no Form object found something like this so I removed FormRequest and instead used Request.
Now I am getting error "TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).**name**"
I am sure this code is far from working yet but I need to fix this error that I don't understand why it is happening.
Power shell shows this line reference number.

```
}], callback=self.parse)
```

Comment: What is the formatted error message? The line you have pasted in the question appears to be the line of code that is raising the exception and not the resulting message.

Comment: Show us the full error traceback!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this part:

```
return scrapy.Request(response,cookies=[{
                'appActionToken':token,
                'appAction':appAction,
                'siteState':siteState,
                'openid.return_to':openid,
                'prevRID':prevRID,
                'workflowState':workflowState,
                'email':'....@gmail.com',
                'create':create,
                'passwrod':'....',
                'metadata1':metadata1,
                }], callback=self.parse)
```

Your first parameter is a response object, whereas Scrapy expects a url here. If you want to make another request to the same url, you can just put `return scrapy.Request(response.url,cookies=[{...}], dont_filter=True)`.

I highly doubt this will work though.. A FormRequest is usually the way to go when you want to login.